# Oracle Homework - SQL Statement error

Tags: sql

I am getting the error ORA-00936: missing expression on the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT || first_name || ' ' || last_name || AS "Possible Candidates"
from EMPLOYEES
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%s';
```

I am trying to get the first name, last name and display them in a single column titled "Possible Candidates" where the last letter of the last name is "s".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS "Possible Candidates"
from EMPLOYEES
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%s';
```

Comment: Excellent! Looks like I had too many pipes. Thanks for the quick reply!